# Clear a typed character during runtime in jTextField

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield, keyevent

```
private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
int x=evt.getKeyCode();
if(x>=96&&x<=105)
  {
      evt.setKeyCode(8);//Here 8 is used for Backspace key to remove the numeric character entered
  }
```

Int This code i want the user not to type any numeric value in jTextField but if he does so then i m trying to remove it off during runtime only.... I wrote this code but its not working as i expected it to be...
**Plzz Help me!!**

Comment: Don't ask the same question in two different ways; merge this question with your first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Force user not to enter numeric entry in JTextField in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285667/force-user-not-to-enter-numeric-entry-in-jtextfield-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

You really should avoid `KeyListeners`, they are too limiting for what you are ultimately trying to achieve and you're only going to end up with a mutation exception as you try and change the fields document while the field is trying to change the document.

You really should be using a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), that's what it's design for.

```
((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {

            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {

                sb.append(c);

            }

        }

        fb.insertString(offset, text, attr);

    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {

            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {

                sb.append(c);

            }

        }

        fb.replace(offset, length, sb.toString(), attrs);

    }

});
```

This is a really basic example, there are plenty on SO.

Apart from avoiding mutation exceptions, the filter intercepts the update before it reaches the document/field, so the incoming changes won't be visible of the screen, you also capture any paste events or `setText` calls.

Answer (score 0):

While perhaps not the very best way to do it, here is one very simple way.

You can override the `paintComponent()` method of the `JTextField` like this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(text) {

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
    super.paintComponent(grphcs);
    String newStr = "";
    for (char c : getText().toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            newStr += c;
        }
    }
    setText(newStr);

    }
};
```

Comment: Dear loed no, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, change a UI component any in ANY paint method, you'll end up consuming te CPU with repeated repaint requests